# html5 timepicker with moment.js and knockout.js

Tags: html, knockout.js, momentjs

i am trying to let the user choose the time and date of his appointment using momentjs 
with the new HTML5 time input and date input.

THE MARKUP  for date input

```
<input data-bind="value: startDate" type="date" ></input>
<output id=startDate data-bind="text: startDate"></output>
<br />
<input data-bind="value: endDate" type="date"></input>
<output id=endDate data-bind="text: endDate"></output>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

THE JS

```
//var todayDate = (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0],
    viewModel = {
    //reset startDate and EndDate
    startDate: ko.observable(moment(new moment()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")),
    endDate: ko.observable(moment(new moment()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")),
    //set back the endDtate to 2034-04-28
    //endDate: ko.observable("2034-04-28"),
    dateDiff : ko.computed(function () {

      return  moment.duration(this.endDate - this.startDate).humanize();

    })
};

viewModel.startDate.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // Show the updated value in the console
    console.info(newValue.replace(/\D/g,''));
});
viewModel.endDate.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    // Show the updated value in the console
    console.info(newValue.replace(/\D/g,''));
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

THE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/pBFQA/2/

i want that when the user changes the date input it recompute a give the difference back and if the end date is smaller than the start date it makes an alert and set back the end date to the startdate value.

And i want to do the same with the Html5 time picker

thank you

**Update:HTML5 Time**

the Markup

```
<input data-bind="value: startTime" type="Time" ></input>
<output id=startTime data-bind="text: startTime"></output>
<br />
<input data-bind="value: endTime" type="Time"></input>
<output id=endTime data-bind="text: endTime"></output>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

the JS

```
    viewModel = {
    //reset startTime and EndTime
    startTime: ko.observable(moment().format('HH:mm:ss')),
    endTime: ko.observable(moment().format('HH:mm:ss')),
    timeDiff : ko.computed(function () {
      console.log(this.startTime);
      console.log(this.endTime);
      return  moment.duration(this.endTime - this.startTime).humanize();

    })
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/5Bjzh/1/

How can i update `timeDiff` on input change?

Comment: Ok, but what is your question? What is not working?

Comment: @nemesv i want that when the user changes the time input it recompute a give the difference back

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, I don't see a time comparison anywhere...  Maybe be more specific

Comment: @PW Kad "ihr Termin dauert 4 hours"  12:52 - 8:32

Comment: If you could let me know what is not working about my answer I can update it for you, should be what you are looking for though

Comment: somehow i can not combine your solution with the new js fiddle i posted there for i can't tell you what s wrong with you solution

Comment: The end all solution is to take moment ot of your view model except in your computed, since you are returning a distance in time.  Treat your date time objects as just that and format them on the client for your html5 control.  I will try to update the fiddle with that later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems in your jsFiddle.

First, you are trying to calculate the time difference and times based off of non-observable properties that are outside of your view model.  Move them inside and calculate them with a computed observable.

```
function viewModel() {    
    var self = this;
    self.startTime = ko.observable(moment('8:32'));
    self.endTime = ko.observable(moment('12:52'));
    self.timeDiff = ko.computed(function () {
        console.log(self.startTime());
        console.log(self.endTime());
        return 'Difference - ' + moment.duration(self.endTime() - self.startTime()).humanize();

    });
});
```

Next, your moments are being formatted before they get to the view - that's a no-no.  Create a valid moment and format them with a binding handler, such as this one -

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Time = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var date = moment(value());
        var strDate = date.format('h:mm a');
        $(element).text(strDate);
    }
};
```

Last, you need to move your subscriptions and other code that is view model specific into your view model.  When it is all said and done it should look something like this -

```
function viewModel() {    
    var self = this;
    self.startTime = ko.observable(new moment());
    self.endTime = ko.observable(new moment());
    self.timeDiff = ko.computed(function () {
        return 'Difference - ' + moment.duration(self.endTime() - self.startTime()).humanize();

    });
    self.MyDate = ko.observable(new Date());
    self.log = ko.observable("");
    self.logDate = function () { 
        self.log(self.log() + self.MyDate());
    };
    self.MyDate.subscribe(function (date) {    
        self.logDate();    
    });
    self.logDate();
};
```

Last, I think you need to double check the moment.duration() method, I don't see how you are trying to compare two dates with it and it doesn't appear to work that way.

**EDIT**

This is a work in progress fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/8N9qC/4/  You still have some work to do to compute the time difference the way that you want it, so look into something like self.startTime().diff(self.endtime());

Comment: I had a fiddle but I think I deleted it let me see - never mind I just added it to the answer, still needs some work but it is a step in the right direction.